# Could not find mapbox vision sdk dependencies

Tags: mapbox-android

I try to set up the Mapbox vision sample app (https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-vision-android), but not able to test the Mapbox Vision SDK sample app.
Dependency files are not downloading due to the Forbidden error.

Error :
Could not GET 'https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox/com/mapbox/navigator/mapbox-navigation-native/7.0.0/mapbox-navigation-native-7.0.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project.

Could you please share the details for how to fix this issue?

Followed the instructions mentioned on https://docs.mapbox.com/android/vision/guides/install/ page and used new tokens but the same issue still exists.

Gradle file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox" }
        maven {
            url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v1/vision/android/maven'
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
            credentials {
                username "mapbox"
                password 'MAP_BOX_KEY'
            }
        }
        maven { url 'http://raw.github.com/saki4510t/libcommon/master/repository/' }
    }

}
```

Gradle dependency :

```
implementation "com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:$mapbox_sdk"
implementation "com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:$mapbox_navigation"
implementation "com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:$mapbox_navigation"
implementation "com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:$mapbox_core"
implementation "com.mapbox.vision:mapbox-android-vision:0.13.0"
implementation "com.mapbox.vision:mapbox-android-vision-ar:0.13.0"
implementation "com.mapbox.vision:mapbox-android-vision-safety:0.13.0"

implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-turf:5.8.0'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-geojson:5.8.0'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-core:5.8.0'

implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-services:5.8.0'
```